# AJAX and HTML element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, getelementbyid

I am trying to set a div tag to display a message if user isn't found in the database.

This is the line I can't get to work:

```js
$("message").html(msg);
```

If you could help me understand what I'm doing wrong it would help.  Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var code = $("#code").val();
        var msg = "Who are you?!";
        var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&code='+ code;
        localStorage.setItem("number",code);
        if(username==''||code=='')
        {
            alert("Um..you are missing something...");
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "verify.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    if(result != 0)
                    alert(result);
                },
                error: function(){
                    $("message").html(msg);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

My PHP code

```php
<?php
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $code = trim($_POST["code"]);

    include_once './inc/config.php';
    $con = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM info WHERE First_Name='".$username."' AND Line_Number='".$code."'" ;
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows != 0){
        echo true;
    }
    else{
        //echo "Who are you?!";
        return false;
    }
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: `$("message").html(msg);` is wrong... what is `message`? is it an `id` or a `class`? based on that you need to use a id-selector or class-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your message element has the **ID** `message`, select it like this:

```
$("#message").html(msg);
```

If it has the **class** `message`, select it like this:

```
$(".message").html(msg);
```

The [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) contains an overview and in-depth description of all selector types.

---

In addition, to trigger the error method in your Javascript, your server-side code needs to send a HTTP error code, for example like this:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
```

Or like this:

```
http_response_code(404);
```

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE! I've learned something new and got it to work!

Answer (score 0):

To target a div with id message use

```
$("#message")
```

You have missed the #

Try this:

```
$.ajax({...
    success: function(data){
        if(data)
            $("#message").html (msg);
        else
            alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `message` a class or an ID? Make sure that you use the proper selector on which your output is to be displayed.

Comment: @Ana Bee : then what is `message` as your selector?

Comment: message is the id to a div tag.

Comment: @AnaBee Replace `$('message').html(msg)` with `$('#message').text(msg)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  error: function(){
    $("message").html(msg);
  }
```

Do you respond with 404 or anything else, except of 2xx, when user is not found? And, yes, selector is incorrect. Your function will be called only in case of HTTP error during request to the server.

This

```
else{
    //echo "Who are you?!";
    return false;
}
```

will not run your function.
This

```
else{
    //echo "Who are you?!";
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

can do it, but not a very nice solution. The best one is to return something like this

```
$response = array('status' => 'failed', 'text' => 'Whatever');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

and in your success function work with data, check the 'status' and so on.

Comment: i've add my php code. i hope that helps. i'm not really clear on what you are asking.

Comment: your php will not trigger error function. you have either return http 404, for example, or json object with status and your data and work with it in success function.

Comment: ah. what is the ajax request looking for? a server error code?

Comment: Yes, .error is called when ajax request has failed, look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use, # for id and . For class
error: function(){
                    $("#message").html(msg);

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious error in the `message` selector, another  problem I can see is in your code is in your PHP.

Your php code does not return an error condition, it returns a true or false, so always your success callback will be called.

So

```
if($num_rows != 0){
    echo true;
}
else{
    //echo "Who are you?!";
    echo false;
}
```

then

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "verify.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            alert(result);
        } else {
            alert(msg);
            //make sure you use a proper selector here
            $("message").html(msg);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        $("message").html(msg);
    }
});
```